# Show popup with the choices "Continue shopping" and "Go to cart", after adding a product to cart, in Magento

Tags: javascript, fancybox, magento-1.7, popupwindow

I am developing a webshop in Magento Community Edition, ver 1.7. I would like to show a popup, for the frontend user, when he/she adds an item to the cart.

The popup shall show the two possiblities "Continue shopping" and "Go to cart", in a fancybox-like popup.

Does anybody know a good tutorial, or a free extension, that does that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any body needs this in the future, i found a great extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-pro.html

With the greatest Support ever!!

Answer (score 0):

hey if you want this advanced ajax Cart for pop-up notification item i used Ajax Cart Advanced its given all features in this extension. so my suggestion is that you can also used this, extension refer below link.

http://shop.syncwebagency.com/n19-ajax-cart-advanced.html

http://shop.syncwebagency.com